# Hibernate & Derby: hbm2dll does not create sequences

Tags: hibernate, maven, jpa-2.0, java-ee-6, derby

I'm using the `hibernate3-maven-plugin` to call `hbm2ddl` to export the ddl for my entities.

This ddl file is then used by `dbmaintain` to initialize an embedded derby database.

But when I launch my Java Enterprise application with this database, I get the following error:

```
16:48:41.714 ERROR [main] o.h.util.JDBCExceptionReporter: SEQUENCE 'HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE' does not exist.
```

...which is correct, because the only code in the generated ddl file that is not directly related to my entities is the following:

```
create table hibernate_unique_key (
     next_hi integer 
);

insert into hibernate_unique_key values ( 0 );
```

The file doesn't contain anything about sequences.

It works if I don't use `dbmaintain` and just set `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` to `update`, but that's nothing I want to use in production (as most sources advice against it).

Shouldn't the ddl generated by `hbm2ddl` contain everything that is needed by hibernate?

#### Maven configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate3-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
        <components>
            <component>
                <name>hbm2ddl</name>
                <implementation>jpaconfiguration</implementation>
            </component>
        </components>
        <componentProperties>
            <persistenceunit>MyPersistenceUnitName</persistenceunit>
            <outputfilename>schema.ddl</outputfilename>
            <drop>false</drop>
            <create>true</create>
            <export>false</export>
            <format>true</format>
        </componentProperties>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

#### persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="MyPersistenceUnitName">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:app/jdbc/MyPersistenceUnitName</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.validation.group.pre-persist" value="some.ServerValidation" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.validation.group.pre-update" value="some.ServerValidation" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was finally able to figure it out:

The problem was that the dependencies of the (latest) [hibernate3-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/maven-hibernate3/hibernate3-maven-plugin/project-info.html) are completely outdated and could not handle my JPA 2.0 annotations.

I got a list of the plugin's dependencies by calling `mvn -X hibernate3:hbm2ddl` and fixed the problem by manually overriding all hibernate dependencies of the plugin to the latest versions:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate3-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <components>
            <component>
                <name>hbm2ddl</name>
                <implementation>jpaconfiguration</implementation>
            </component>
        </components>
        <componentProperties>
            <persistenceunit>MyPersistenceUnitName</persistenceunit>
            <outputfilename>schema.ddl</outputfilename>
            <drop>false</drop>
            <create>true</create>
            <export>false</export>
            <format>true</format>
        </componentProperties>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-tools</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.8.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```